# Сортировка списка List с классами по алфавиту

Tags: c#, сортировка, list

Есть к примеру список в котором хранятся обьекты класса , как сделать так чтобы отсортировать список в алфавитном порядке по фамилии `Surname`?

```cs
List<Worker> workers = new List<Worker>();
workers.Add(new Worker { Name = "Donald", Surname = "Trump" , Vacancy = "Dev", Joined = 2015 });
workers.Add(new Worker { Name = "Barak", Surname = "Obama" , Vacancy = "HR", Joined = 2011 });
workers.Add(new Worker { Name = "Joe", Surname = "Biden" , Vacancy = "Team lead", Joined = 2020 });
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0

Comment: @MarkShevchenko workers.Sort(Worker.Surname); - не работает :)

Comment: да, не работает, и не должно. По ссылке очень подробная статья на русском языке с примером, похожим на ваш. Надо прочитать и разобраться.

Comment: `workers = workers.OrderBy(w=>w.LastName).ToList()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас есть 2 основные опции:

- `IEnumerable<T>.OrderBy(..)`
- `List<T>.Sort(..)`

Допустим, `Worker` - это запись. У вас это может быть класс, не важно, я взял запись только ради удобного вывода в консоль.

```cs
record Worker
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Vacancy { get; set; }
    public int Joined { get; set; }
}
```

Тогда `Linq` будет выглядеть так

```cs
foreach (Worker worker in workers.OrderBy(w => w.Surname))
{
    Console.WriteLine(worker);
}
```

А `List.Sort` будет выглядеть так

```cs
workers.Sort((left, right) => left.Surname.CompareTo(right.Surname));
foreach (Worker worker in workers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(worker);
}
```

Вывод в консоль одинаковый

```
Worker { Name = Joe, Surname = Biden, Vacancy = Team lead, Joined = 2020 }
Worker { Name = Barak, Surname = Obama, Vacancy = HR, Joined = 2011 }
Worker { Name = Donald, Surname = Trump, Vacancy = Dev, Joined = 2015 }
```

Но механика работы разная. В первом случае вы сортируете только вывод в консоль, а список остается неизменным, а во втором случае сортируется именно сам список.